# Ubuntu 18.04: Black screen on boot connected to Samsung TV

Tags: 18.04, screen, hdmi, tv

I have a problem with my 3 year old 'htpc' computer stationed in my living room, running Ubuntu 18.04. After the Asus UEFI/BIOS splash screen, the screen gets black and the system is totally freezed. It does not react to any input. The only way out is to turn it off/reboot.

It is connected to my 2013 55" Samsung TV 55UE8005 via HDMI, and I suspect that it has to do with the problem. It uses the motherboard graphics processor, thus no separate graphics card.

My 'htpc' computer consists of:

- Intel Core i3 6100 3,7GHz Socket 1151 Box
- Noctua NH-L9i CPU cooler
- Samsung 850 EVO Series MZ-N5E250BW 250GB (SSD)
- Asus H170I-Plus D3 (mini-ITX motherboard)
- Corsair Vengeance DDR3 PC12800/1600MHz CL10 LP 8GB (DDR3-memory)
- External Mini-ITX Power kit 160w/192w (fanless) Picopsu 160XT / AC-DC 12v 16A 192w adapter

Some more info:

martin@htpc:~$ sudo lshw | grep -A9 VGA
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: HD Graphics 530
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
martin@htpc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
martin@htpc:~$

martin@htpc:~$ uname -a
Linux htpc 4.18.0-15-generic #16~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Feb 7 14:06:04 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
martin@htpc:~$

To the story, I can add that in the beginning, I used this exact same 'htpc' without any problems with the exact same TV and setup! However, during the years I have upgraded Ubuntu multiple times and at some point (like a year ago), it started to fail as described.

I have tried to troubleshoot this, but failed to solve it. Here are my findings:

Having the 'htpc' connected to my 24" Eizo monitor, using VGA, it boots up perfectly! This makes me believe it has to do with the graphics driver being non-compatible with my TV.

Tried to connect it to another extra monitor, 19" HP EM869A, (old one from Aug 2007) using VGA. Essentially the same problem occurs, however at freeze point, I notice sometimes a couple of random-placed multi-coloured dots in the top of the black screen.

Towards the TV, I have used two different HDMI-HDMI cables. No diff.

Tried HDMI - DisplayPort cable. No diff.

Upgraded (today) to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS HWE (now running the 4.18 kernel release) - no difference.

Edited 'grub' settings to:

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
>   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
>   GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
>   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nopat vesafb.invalid=1 drm.debug=0xe
>   plymouth:debug" GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="xdg.force_integrated=1"
>
> GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=text GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

I have also added the following xorg conf file (based on some google answer):

martin@htpc:~$ more /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-intel.conf 
Section "OutputClass"
   Identifier "Intel"
   MatchDriver "i915"
   Driver "intel"
EndSection
martin@htpc:~$

...without any difference.

So, now, I am out of ideas. :-( Is there someone that can help me further?
Many thanks in advance!

BR Martin

Comment: Have you tried with another monitor?

Comment: Yes, as previously mentioned, I have tried my old 19" HP monitor, with the result mentioned above. I can also add that I have brought my computer to work and tried it against a third monitor, a 24" Dell and it worked perfectly fine! Just as fine as my 24" Eizo monitor at home.

Comment: If it's specific to one device, it may just be incompatible

Comment: Well, since I have had the exact same setup working fine for years (previously), I believe there is some new settings or something that gives this problem. I can add that going into grub (which is very hard, by some unknown reason?), I can choose the first 'ubuntu' option and my system boots up perfectly together with the TV. Thus, I know it works together.

Comment: My problem with grub is to get into grub menu. I try to press 'left shift' or 'right shift' repeatedly during the bootup process, but only once out of maybe 30 times, I succeed. :-( Then, I will be able to boot up Ubuntu 18.04 towards my TV as explained in last comment.  If someone can give me tips on how to enter grub easier, I am very grateful.